# Unix Shell Scripting ifelse error

Tags: shell, unix, if-statement, scripting

Please help, This script gives following error while executing :

Then unexpected 
Str1 not found 
Str2 not found

```
#!/bin/ksh 

echo ">>Please press y or n :"
read Str

Str1="y"
Str2="n"
if[[$Str1 == $Str]];then
echo "You pressed Y."
elif[[$Str2 == $Str]]; then
echo "You pressed N."
else
echo "Error."
fi
```

Comment: Error 1 : Syntax error : 'then' unexpected 

Error 2 : 'Str1' Not found 

Error 3 : 'Str2' Not found

Comment: Use http://shellcheck.net - I really wish that I could find a decent duplicate for this common issue related to missing spaces around `[`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing whitespaces.

```
#!/bin/ksh 

echo ">>Please press y or n :"
read Str

Str1="y"
Str2="n"
if [[ $Str1 == $Str ]]; then
    echo "You pressed Y."
elif [[ $Str2 == $Str ]]; then
    echo "You pressed N."
else
    echo "Error."
fi
```